# getView problems setting Listener with position

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with an `Adapter` that is using a `LruCache` as it's `ViewHolder`. I'm attempting to retrieve a `View` from the cache inside `getView()` and set a `onLongClickListener`. However despite my efforts I seem to get the last index in my cache every single time.

**Adapter**

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LruCache<Integer, View> mViewCache;
        private Context mContext;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private MyAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mViewCache = new LruCache<Integer, View>(10);
        }

        private View inflateMyView(ViewGroup parent, View view) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, null);
            return view;
        }
```

**getView**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = mViewCache.get(position);

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflateMyView(parent, null);
        mViewCache.put(position, view);
    }
    ...
    ...
view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
```

So as you can now see my `onLongClickListener` only works on the last item I added to my list(last index in my cache). I need each item in my list to have this `Listener` attached, not just the last. Any help is appreciated, I've been staring at this too long.

**Edit (FYI)**
Due to the tightly coupled nature of this code the `onLongClickListener` must remain inside `getView`. Which is why I'm so frustrated. If this has to move it becomes a totally different solution

Comment: Is your `getView` inside `MyAdapter` class?

Comment: @ZhenxiaoHao yes, and unfortunately I set my listener inside getView. Most of this code is tightly coupled and I lack the scope of knowledge and time to perform the deep refactoring needed on the parent elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()` in your `getView` method and let it `return convertView`. set the `onLongClickListener` after you setting the `adapter` for your `ListView`:

```
listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

});
```

Comment: +1 This is a good solution, however because of how this code is coupled the listener must remain inside `getView()`. Which is why I'm having so much trouble. The amount of refactoring needed to make this solution work is far too much. Thanks for the effort though.